# Directory Size in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Since NSFileManager has no capabilities of returning the size of a directory, what would be a suitable & fast method for obtaining directory size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no fast method: you have to recursively request size of every file in the directory hierarchy.

Don't forget to handle special cases:

- files (or directories on a Time Machine volume) with multiple hard links: count them only once.
- special files such as what is found in `/dev` but can be created everywhere.
- symbolic links: don't follow them, but count their size.

Depending on your needs, you also have to choose between size of file contents or size of file on disk.

Answer (score 2):

Enumerate all directories inside your folder.
"Folder size will be = Sum of All file sizes in side that folder."

Some options:

1. Programatically doing the same I suggest opendir with readdir_r to enumarate all files -- based on its CPU and Memory.
2. You can run du command using shell.

There are other options too ... it depend on how you want to do.

Comment: Is du have different behavior on different version of MAC OSX?

Comment: I never find a difference ... even if you find any deference you can build du from open source and keep it with you app to use in all OS